# Firebase DB: Application has opened too many files. Maximum of available file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default

Tags: android, database, firebase, sqlite

I'm getting the following error in Firebase. My code doesn't open any files directly, but it works extensively with HttpOK, WebRTC and overall networking. Does networking also using file descriptors? Since the error is not raised by my code, I'm curious how I can fix it. Can I see somehow where and which file descriptors open? (then I can find what causes the descriptors leaks).

> 2021-06-13 04:14:59.610 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia
> E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database
> '/data/user/0/com.mafialab.mafia/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db'.
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 2062): Could not open database
> #################################################################
> Error Code : 2062 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EMFILE)
> Caused By : Application has opened too many files. Maximum of available file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default.
> (unknown error (code 2062): Could not open database)
> #################################################################
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:262)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:649)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:255)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:222)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1191)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1146)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:861)
> at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:729)
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:310)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:254)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:194)
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzef.getWritableDatabase(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeg.zzo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeg.zzq(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:6)
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeg.zzi(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:9)
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzjk.zzl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:6)
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhw.zzu(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:147)
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:1)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfq.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:6)
> 2021-06-13 04:14:59.619 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia E/FA: Opening
> the local database failed, dropping and recreating it 2021-06-13
> 04:14:59.622 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia W/SQLiteLog: (28) failed
> to open
> "/data/user/0/com.mafialab.mafia/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db"
> with flag (131138) and mode_t (0) due to error (24) 2021-06-13
> 04:14:59.622 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia W/SQLiteLog: (28) failed
> to open
> "/data/user/0/com.mafialab.mafia/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db"
> with flag (131072) and mode_t (0) due to error (24) 2021-06-13
> 04:14:59.622 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot
> open file at line 36170 of [4bb21d8205] 2021-06-13 04:14:59.622
> 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:36170: (24)
> open(/data/user/0/com.mafialab.mafia/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db)
>
> - 2021-06-13 04:14:59.622 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia E/SQLiteLog: (1) Process  : Pid (30892) Uid (10190) Euid (10190) Gid (10190) Egid
>   (10190) 2021-06-13 04:14:59.624 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia
>   E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database
>   '/data/user/0/com.mafialab.mafia/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db'.
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 2062): Could not open database
>   #################################################################
>   Error Code : 2062 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EMFILE)
>   Caused By : Application has opened too many files. Maximum of available file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default.
>   (unknown error (code 2062): Could not open database)
>   #################################################################
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:262)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:649)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:255)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:222)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1191)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1146)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:861)
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:729)
>   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:310)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:254)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:194)
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzef.getWritableDatabase(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:9)
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeg.zzo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:1)
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeg.zzq(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:6)
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzeg.zzi(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:9)
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzjk.zzl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:6)
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhw.zzu(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:147)
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:1)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfq.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:6)
>   2021-06-13 04:14:59.625 30892-30994/com.mafialab.mafia E/FA: Failed to
>   open local database. Events will bypass local storage:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error
>   (code 2062): Could not open database
>   #################################################################
>   Error Code : 2062 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EMFILE)
>   Caused By : Application has opened too many files. Maximum of available file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default.
>   (unknown error (code 2062): Could not open database)
>   #################################################################: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzef.getWritableDatabase(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@19.0.0:9)

Comment: In which case you get this error ? (on startup or sometime in runtime ). Some resources which use app can be a files : shared-prefs, raw  resources, assets, sqlite db, log files. May be the app try to init  some analytics  recursively or in cycle. May be when your app  each time try to save(or read) something you create new instance of some object (like save logs) which opens file and not close a file after completing .

Comment: Nothing of this applies. The app using webrtc, I strongly suspect  it related. My question is how I can check number of open handlers in runtime? If I know this I could find which part of code causes it. I don’t work with files or handlers directly in my code, but 3rd party libs can do it

Comment: The error happens when I do extensive webrtc calls with multiple participants. But since the error happens not in webrtc itself but in Firebase (probably crash analytics?), this complicates the debugging process

Comment: What about answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557930/list-all-files-opened-by-my-android-app ? (Some libraries(components) can be started at separate process -  check all of them)

Answer (score 0):

Socket (network or pipes) do indeed have file descriptors.

You can list them :

```
for (f in File("/proc/self/fd").listFiles()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "file : ${f.isFile}, ${f} -> ${f.canonicalPath}")
}
```

```
...
file : false, /proc/self/fd/50 -> /dev/kgsl-3d0
file : false, /proc/self/fd/51 -> /proc/2815/fd/51
file : false, /proc/self/fd/52 -> /proc/2815/fd/52
file : false, /proc/self/fd/53 -> /proc/2815/fd/53
file : false, /proc/self/fd/54 -> /proc/2815/fd/54
file : false, /proc/self/fd/55 -> /proc/2815/fd/55
file : false, /proc/self/fd/56 -> /proc/2815/fd/56
file : false, /proc/self/fd/57 -> /dev/ion
file : false, /proc/self/fd/58 -> /dev/ion
file : false, /proc/self/fd/59 -> /dev/hwbinder
file : true, /proc/self/fd/63 -> /data/app/com.google.android.gms-xErOVYdgUuUxSUGYRGwZ0A==/split_config.en.apk
file : true, /proc/self/fd/64 -> /data/app/com.google.android.gms-xErOVYdgUuUxSUGYRGwZ0A==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
```

On Android 8.0+ (API level 26), it is possible to get a bit more details :

```
for (f in File("/proc/self/fd").listFiles()) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "file : ${f.isFile}, ${f} -> ${java.nio.file.Files.readSymbolicLink(f.toPath())}")
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get info for $f")
    }
}
```

```
...
file : false, /proc/self/fd/50 -> /dev/kgsl-3d0
file : false, /proc/self/fd/51 -> socket:[3647176]
file : false, /proc/self/fd/52 -> socket:[3648033]
file : false, /proc/self/fd/53 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
file : false, /proc/self/fd/54 -> socket:[3648028]
file : false, /proc/self/fd/55 -> socket:[3648030]
file : false, /proc/self/fd/56 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
file : false, /proc/self/fd/57 -> /dev/ion
file : false, /proc/self/fd/58 -> /dev/ion
file : false, /proc/self/fd/59 -> /dev/hwbinder
file : true, /proc/self/fd/63 -> /data/app/com.google.android.gms-xErOVYdgUuUxSUGYRGwZ0A==/split_config.en.apk
file : true, /proc/self/fd/64 -> /data/app/com.google.android.gms-xErOVYdgUuUxSUGYRGwZ0A==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
```